# How do I export an array of objects and it's properties to another JS file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, webpack

My ongoing school project entails me to use WebPack, the static module bundler. Now what I'm trying to do is export

```
const data = [
  {
    description: "Go swimming",
    completed: true,
    index: 1,
  },
  {
    description: "Create an animated puppet",
    completed: false,
    index: 2,
  },
  {
    description: "Hack NASA",
    completed: false,
    index: 2,
  },
];
```

and import it in my functions.js file with the import function. But it's not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). How have you tried doing it? How has it not worked? You almost literally have it in the question (just move the `export` into the code), if you're using ESM (which I suggest doing).

Comment: what is not working here. You can simply export and import array of objects as [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-estrela-3we95?file=/src/function.js)

Answer (score 3):

Webpack supports JavaScript native modules (ESM), which I suggest using. (As opposed to CommonJS [`require` calls and such].)

You almost literally have the export part in the question, just move the `export` into the code block:

```
export const data = [
    // ...
];
```

That's a *named export*. You import it like this (if the above is in `the-source-module.js` in the same directory):

```
import { data } from "./the-source-module.js";
```

> ...with the import function.

There isn't an `import` function, but there's a **very** function-like `import` construct called *dynamic import*. It looks exactly like a function that returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). If that's what you're being told to use (instead of an `import` declaration as above), it would look like this:

In an environment that supports top-level `await` (Webpack does):

```
const { data } = await import("./the-source-module.js");
// ...use `data` here...
```

In an environment that doesn't:

```
import("./the-source-module.js")
.then(({data}) => {
    // ...use `data` here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...import failed...
});
// DON'T TRY TO USE `data` HERE, IT WON'T WORK
```

More on MDN:

- [Modules overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)
- [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)
- [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) (includes dynamic [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_import))

I also cover modules in Chapter 13 of my recent book [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev) *(and promises in Chapter 8, and all the other ES2015-ES2020 stuff)*.

---

**Note:** The use of `{}` in `import { data } from ...` may look a bit like destructuring, but it **isn't** destructuring. Other than the `{}`, but the semantics and syntax of named imports and destructuring are quite different. For instance, if you wanted to use a name other than `data`, it would be `import { data as yourName } from ...`, which is not how renaming works with destructuring.

Slightly confusingly, the examples above with dynamic `import()` *are* using destructuring. The promise "returned" by `import()` is fulfilled with an object called a "module namespace object" that has a property for each named export. That along with its dynamic nature is a fundamental difference between dynamic `import()` and `import` declarations.

Comment: why do you not suggest commonjs? module.exports and require would do the same job, right?

Comment: @sediballiu - Two reasons: 1. Because ESM is standard now, the only actually-specified module mechanism, and tooling now focusses on it rather than CommonJS. 2. For all the reasons CommonJS wasn't used as the standard module format: Static semantics, live bindings rather than value copies (which helps immensely with cyclic structures), async handling of dynamic imports, ... But yes, for now, you could use CommonJS instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, it exported it successfully.